# App not relaunch from background but delegate is called didReceiveIncomingConnection twilio in ios

Tags: ios, twilio, voip

I am working on a VoIP application. I have some problem that the app is not relaunching from background state (not coming to foreground state) but

```
(void)device:(TCDevice *)device didReceiveIncomingConnection:(TCConnection *)connection
```

is called.

I can post a local notification but it does not look good when calling.

I also want to know how all other VoIP apps handle calling in background. How do they relaunch the app in those applications like Skype and WhatsApp?

Comment: I think I would try to check the app state when that delegate method is called and check the Application state. If the Application is backgrounded maybe you can post a notification to either initiate a background task with an action button to connect and start the VoIP session or use the push to open the app.

Comment: sir my delegate is call and I succesfully navigate to that caller screen but app state is not change to foreground.

Comment: You can't just force your app to visibly foreground from the background without user interaction if that's what you mean. If your app is in the background, you can still initiate a VoIP call if you register for background VoIP audio in your plist, but there is no way to activate and switch to your app from a call any way other than prompting the user to open the app from a push.

Comment: Thanks sir I have understood :). I will implement it.